# ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'comment' in field list

Tags: mysql, sql

I work with MySQL 5.5. I have a table `comment`.
When I make this query:

```
 select sum(case when comment.entity_id=1 and comment.entity_type=1 then 1 else 0 end) as result1;
```

I get

```
ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'comment' in field list
```

This should not happen, since

```
select * from comment;
```

works just fine.

Where is the error?

Comment: Well, I'd add that `FROM comment` at the end then.....

Comment: @Wrikken Ok... that was it... Thank you! Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a FROM clause:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN entity_id = 1 AND entity_type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS result1
FROM comment
```